# flutter Error the screen overflows horizontally

Tags: flutter, user-interface, singlechildscrollview

I want to scroll the overflowing screen horizontally.
I used SingleChildScrollView, but the widget was not visible.
I've tried both listview and SingleChildScrollView, but I keep getting a notification that the size of the horizontal axis is the problem. "A RenderFlex overflowed by 163 pixels on the right."

```
>   if (forChart)
>     Container(
>       child: SingleChildScrollView(
>         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>         child: Row(
>           children: [
>             Container(
>               width: 160.0,
>               color: Colors.yellow,),
>             Container(
>               width: 160.0,
>               color: Colors.yellow,),
>             Container(
>               width: 160.0,
>               color: Colors.yellow,),
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
>     )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIFVe.png)

Comment: can you provide the image of the overflowed error?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, I could not reproduce your error. Can you post a more complete code snippet? Cheers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>   if (forChart)
>     Container(
        height: 200,
        width:double.maxFinite
>       child: SingleChildScrollView(
>         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
>         child: Row(
>           children: [
>             Container(
>               width: 160.0,
>               color: Colors.yellow,),
>             Container(
>               width: 160.0,
>               color: Colors.yellow,),
>             Container(
>               width: 160.0,
>               color: Colors.yellow,),
>           ],
>         ),
>       ),
>     )
```

Wrap your container to Expanded widget if you are using column widget as parent or else provide height and width to container.